# Reading memory pointers freeze process

Tags: c++, pointers, integer, compare

I was trying to read some addresses inside a game process and then compare then with a integer number.

My code is the following:

```
BOOL SCMemoryCheat::CheckDKHack()
{
        int *DkAddr1 = (int*)0x87016C + 0x11E4; // Pointer DK 1
        memcpy(DKBytesValues1, DkAddr1, 16);

        int *DkAddr2 = (int*)0x87016C + 0x1224; // Pointer DK 2
        memcpy(DKBytesValues2, DkAddr2, 16);

        if (   DKBytesValues1[0] == DKBytesValues1[1]
            && DKBytesValues1[1] == DKBytesValues1[2]
            && DKBytesValues1[2] == DKBytesValues1[3]
            && DKBytesValues1[3] == DKBytesValues1[4]
            && DKBytesValues1[4] == DKBytesValues1[5]
            && DKBytesValues1[0] == 0x00)
        {
            // DK Detected
            return TRUE;
        }

}

bool StartSCMemoryCheats()
{
    SCMemoryCheat* SCMemC = new SCMemoryCheat;

    while (TRUE)
    {
        int *ChannelIDAddr = (int*)0x8915AF;
        int *p = (int*)255;

        if (ChannelIDAddr == p)
        {
          if (SCMemC->CheckDKHack)
          {
            delete[] SCMemC;
            break;
          }
        }

        ExitProcess(0);
    }



}
```

and the class:

```
class SCMemoryCheat
{
    unsigned char *DKBytesValues1 = new unsigned char[16];
    unsigned char *DKBytesValues2 = new unsigned char[16];

    unsigned char *XFS = new unsigned char[4];

    public:
        SCMemoryCheat();
        virtual ~SCMemoryCheat();
        BOOL CheckDKHack();
};
```

**bool StartSCMemoryCheats()** is called with a thread, this way:

```
DWORD dwSMCThreadId = 0;
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&StartSCMemoryCheats,(LPVOID) NULL, 0, &dwSMCThreadId);
```

It COMPILES, but doesnt work and the process get freezed with +/- 30% of CPU use.

How could I do this comparison?

**EDIT**

FIXED SOME STUFF

but now this condition ALWAYS returns TRUE, and the value IS 255.

```
    **volatile int *ChannelIDAddr = (int*)0x8915AF;

    // Check world list
    if (*ChannelIDAddr != 255)
    {
       // ALWAYS TRUE
     }**
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `while` loop just compares the pointers, it doesn't indirect through them. You also should declare the values `volatile`, so the compiler doesn't optimize it away.

Comment: so how could I get the value (1 byte) of the pointer, and then compare it with a integer value?

Comment: Given a pointer `p`, `*p` gets the value that it points to.

Comment: What integer are you trying to compare with? `int *p = (int *)255` declares a pointer to the memory location 255, not the integer 255.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
while (TRUE)
{
    volatile int *ChannelIDAddr = (int*)0x8915AF;
    const int p = 255;

    if (*ChannelIDAddr == p)
    {
      if (SCMemC->CheckDKHack())
      {
        delete[] SCMemC;
        break;
      }
    }

    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

If you want to compare with the integer `255`, you should declare `p` as an `int`, not a pointer. You need to indirect through `ChannelIDAddr` with the `*` prefix to read the value there. And it should be declared `volatile` so that the compiler won't optimize repeated reads of the same pointer.

Finally, since `CheckDKHack` is a function, you call it by putting `()` after it.

Comment: Hmm ok but it crashs the process. How about the function CheckDKHack, is everything ok? I just read 16 bytes from the address and then compare the first 5 with 00

Comment: Maybe the declarations in CheckDKHack should be `int *DkAddr1 = (int*)(0x87016C + 0x11E4);`. The way you wrote it, `0x11E4` will be multiplied by the size of integers, not a number of bytes. Without know what the intent is, I don't know what's right.

Comment: Yeah I should not multiply it. Just fixed it.